# Is singing a gramman considered kol isha?

Tags: halacha, kol-isha

Is [a gramman](/q/36384) considered "*singing*", with regards to *kol isha*? On the one hand, it is more of a reading of a poem with intonation and a chorus of *na na na*s interspersed. On the other hand, it has the ring of a song.

Comment: Welcome to mi.yodeya, daniella!

Comment: If a chorus of men sing it, there's no problem of *kol isha*. Your question doesn't specify who is singing.

Comment: @DanF I think mentioning *kol isha* implies the subject of the singing.

Comment: @DanF - The OP mentions `with regards to _kol isha_` and so it is assumed that she is talking about a _woman_ singing a grammen.

Comment: Hi Daniella and welcome to Mi Yodeya. I've heard grommin many times. As far as I can tell, it is singing. It has a tune. So, it seems that it would fall under all the regulations of Kol Isha. Keep in mind that there are differing opinions that may make it permissible if there's a mixed men's women's group or even if two or more women are singing together. As you're not asking for a general source of opinions on *Kol Isha*, I haven't included a link for that. However, I still don't follow why you would think that grammin is not singing if it has a tune. They're not just speaking.